# how to bind "Droppable" and "Draggable " Events in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js

How to implement jquery ui Drag,Drop Events in Backbone , so I can get
the event when drop happened , as drop is not implemented in backbone by default , how to do that ?

How could i bind jquery ui Droppable events Like :

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
      hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var pos = ui.draggable.offset(), dPos = $(this).offset();   alert("nodeid: " +  $(ui.draggable).attr("id")  + 
        ", Top: " + (pos.top - dPos.top) + 
        ", Left: " + (pos.left - dPos.left));
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
```

Comment: Can't you just include jQuery UI and bind them like you would normally?

Comment: @trojan :: I have to implement in backbone view events .If you know share .

Comment: I haven't used backbone before; I just thought it might be possible to bind them with jQuery UI as you would normally, then do whatever you wanted with backbone.

Comment: Like http://jsfiddle.net/eLLmW/24/ , but HOw

Answer (score 3):

Each of the jQuery UI events an event name that you can use, for example in your view:

```
// View class
events: {
    "drop #droppable": "callback"
},

callback: function( event, ui ) {
    var pos = ui.draggable.offset(), 
        dPos = $(this).offset();   alert("nodeid: " + $(ui.draggable).attr("id")  + 
    ", Top: " + (pos.top - dPos.top) + 
    ", Left: " + (pos.left - dPos.left));
    $( event.currentTarget )
      .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
      .find( "p" )
        .html( "Dropped!" );
},

render: function(){ // or equivalent render function
    $("#droppable").droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active"
    });
}
```

For reference, the Backbone View events are the equivalent of:

```
$(view.el).on(eventName, selector, callback);
```

where:

```
events: {
    "eventName selector": "callback"
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I am getting your point, working on it. Many thanks for reply.